# Playframework: cannot override sbt dependency

Tags: scala, playframework, dependencies, sbt, overriding

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```sh
echo '
   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena-libs" % "3.17.0" ;
   lazy val testPlay = (project in file(".")) .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
' > build.sbt ;
mkdir project ;
echo 'addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.5")'
  > project/plugins.sbt ;
sbt run
```

I have a dependency to a Java module (Apache Jena), that specifies jackson-core 2.11.3 , while latest Play is at 2.10.4 . Play does not start in dev mode:

```
JsonMappingException: Scala module 2.10.4 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.10.0 and < 2.11.0.
```

I tried this:

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.10.4"
```

but it is not taken in account, checking with `show fullClasspath` and `dependencyTree` .
Also tried excludeDependencies in two ways, specifying 2.10.4 or 2.11.3 . My understanding is that

1. a Java dependency cannot be changed by SBT `excludeDependencies`
2. function `play.runsupport.Reloader.startDevMode()` is not
   affected by main SBT configuration, because it is part of the Play
   plugin ; indeed the class Reloader is not in `play-server_2.12-2.8.5.jar`

So what kind of hack could I try?

The `sbt` config.
https://github.com/jmvanel/semantic_forms/blob/master/scala/project/Common.scala#L44

The stack trace:

```
[error] com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Scala module 2.10.4 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.10.0 and < 2.11.0
[error]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:61)
[error]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule$(JacksonModule.scala:46)
[error]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:17)
[error]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:819)
[error]         at akka.serialization.jackson.JacksonObjectMapperProvider$.$anonfun$configureObjectMapperModules$4(JacksonObjectMapperProvider.scala:223)
[error]         at akka.serialization.jackson.JacksonObjectMapperProvider$.$anonfun$configureObjectMapperModules$4$adapted(JacksonObjectMapperProvider.scala:222)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
[error]         at akka.serialization.jackson.JacksonObjectMapperProvider$.configureObjectMapperModules(JacksonObjectMapperProvider.scala:222)
...
[error]         at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:290)
[error]         at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.$anonfun$mainDev$1(DevServerStart.scala:248)
[error]         at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:22)
[error]         at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDev(DevServerStart.scala:76)
```

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can force a dependency with:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.10.4" force()
```

Another option you have is to exclude dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena-libs" % "3.17.0" exclude("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-databind")
```

Comment: Alas no, this does not change the issue, and
`show fullClasspath` gives jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar ,
which tends to prove that a "Java dependency cannot be changed by SBT"

Comment: minimal reproducible example:

```shell
echo '
  libraryDependencies += "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena-libs" % "3.17.0" ;
  lazy val testPlay = (project in file(".")) .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
' >  build.sbt ;

mkdir project ;
echo 'addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.5")' > 
  project/plugins.sbt ;
```

sbt run

Comment: Indeed adding what you suggested , @tomer-shetah , does not fix :  `libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.10.4" force()`

Comment: Indeed , it works on the toy project, not yet on my application , but this is encouraging :)

Comment: OK for reading the fucking SOF manual :) . For now I try extending the toy project to something more representative of my real life application.